# SQL database queries basic question

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

Relational Schema:

- Employee (Enum, Ename)
- VentingMac (Enum, Cokename, day)

The attribute `Enum` in VentingMac relation is a foreign key referencing the relation Employee.

I want to list out all the employee names (Ename), who drink more than 3 (distinct) coke on the same day
(assuming they wont drink the same coke each day)

Comment: hmm... this smells like a homework question to me. In fact, I'm pretty sure I had almost the exact same problem to do in a DB mgmt class last year.

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted an answer that uses a built in aggregate function when you say you can't use one....????

Comment: yea sorry it was a mistake on my part, we can use function it turn out. I guess I should have edited it. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using EXISTS

```
SELECT e.ename
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM VENTINGMAC vm
               WHERE vm.enum = e.enum
            GROUP BY vm.day, vm.enum
              HAVING COUNT(vm.coke) > 3)
```

### USING IN

```
SELECT e.ename
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE e.enum IN (SELECT vm.enum
                    FROM VENTINGMAC vm
                GROUP BY vm.day, vm.enum
                  HAVING COUNT(vm.coke) > 3)
```

### Using a JOIN:

```
SELECT e.ename
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
  JOIN (SELECT vm.enum
          FROM VENTINGMAC vm
      GROUP BY vm.day, vm.enum
        HAVING COUNT(vm.coke) > 3) y ON y.enum = e.enum
```

### Breakdown

The meat of the query lies in checking the VENTINGMAC table, particularly with aggregate functions (which means needing a GROUP BY clause).  I'm assuming `VENTINGMAC.day` contains a DATE (year, month, day) only -- no time portion to complicate things.  You need to group on the person, and day in the table to be able to count the `coke` values like you see in the `HAVING` clause.